# What is the probability of the formed number being divisible by $2$ and $3$?

Tags: probability

There are 9 notes separately labeled $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$. One by one, two notes are randomly taken and put on a table side by side so that the first note is on the left and the one drawn last is on the right. This creates a two digit number. What is the probability of the formed number being divisible by $2$ and $3$?

Comment: "The first note is put on the left"  What do you mean by the "first" note here?  Do you mean the smaller number is always on the left?  I would have thought since the notes were taken "one by one" the "first" note could have been larger or smaller than the second.

Comment: The first note taken is on the table situated to the left regarding the note picked last

Comment: So, are both $48$ and $84$ possible outcomes... and are these considered different than each other?   I still do not understand the grammar you are using.

Comment: It's no different in that sense, the exercise says that the first note picked has to be situated left regarding to the note picked last.

Comment: That is not at all how I would have interpreted the problem statement.  "First" to me is in reference to the order in which they were selected "one by one" and not in reference to the size comparison of the digits.  I would have expected there to be $72$ outcomes, not $36$.  Nothing in the problem statement as it is currently written in English suggests that the digits in our number must be in ascending order.  If such a condition were present in the intended problem, it must have been lost in translation or you are confused.

Comment: I could have "first" picked a 5 and "then" picked a 4 to get 54 or I could have "first" picked a 4 and "then" picked a 5 to get 45.  One of these was divisible by 6, the other was not.  We look at the nine available notes and take *any* one of them to be our "first" selection.  We then look at the eight remaining available notes and take *any* one of them to be our "second" selection, regardless what was picked first.  That description of the selection process is still consistent with the problem statement.  I still refuse to believe 36 is the intended count of outcomes.

Comment: I think this doesn't really matter, the exercise is written this way.  All the possible outcomes are 72 I think instead. But if you leave that part out, could you help with solving the question? I'll try rephrasing the part that is confusing you.

Comment: If you wanted 36 to be the count of outcomes, the problem statement should have been worded "*Simultaneously, two notes are taken and put on a table so that the smaller is put on the left and the larger is put on the right*"

Comment: "*could you help with solving the question?*"  My help would have been exactly the same as Ethan's below.  Pick your units digit (*it must be even*).  Given a selection of a units digit, pick which tens-digit can pair with it such that the result is a multiple of $3$.  Recognize the special case of having picked $6$ as the units digit as that reduces the number of available tens-digits that could have paired with it.  For the problem where larger digit could be on left *or* right, it all falls under two cases.  For where larger must be on left, every units digit gives its own different case.

Comment: So, there is 72 possible outcomes. And of which 12 are viable. And 0 is not an option. Does the probability of this really come down to P(A) = 12/72 ?

Comment: Check your calculation which yielded $12$.  Again, remember the special case of $6$ as the units digit.  Remember that $66$ is not a valid outcome here as you can not repeat digits.

Comment: Indeed, 66 is not viable, thanks. So, it comes down to P(A) = 11 / 72?

Comment: Yes.  For the related problem where the first digit must be larger than the second there would have been only five outcomes (42, 72, 54, 84, 96) out of $36$ and where the first digit must be smaller than the second there are six outcomes (12, 24, 36, 18, 48, 78) out of $36$.  (*note, 5+6=11*)

Answer (score 2):

Several hints:

There are $72$ possible two digit numbers: 9 choices for the tens place, then 8 for the units place.

Any digit is as likely as any other to end up in the units place. That should help you find the multiples of 2.

A number is divisible by 3 if the sum of its digits is divisible by 3. That should help you tell which tens digits can be combined with which ones digits to find multiples of 3.

Comment: The two digit number in the end has to be dividable by 2 and 3 both, so dividable by six yeah

Comment: Yes, that's right. That suggests another method. Count the two digit multiples of 6. Easier, but less generalizable.

Comment: Aren't there only 36 possible numbers considering the fact that the notes are initially ordered?

Comment: @user That depends on how you read "first note". I interpreted it as "first note picked" but the OP might mean "note with the lower value".

Comment: He writes: "The first note taken is on the table situated to the left regarding the note picked last". It would have no sense if the notes were not ordered.

Comment: @user the order comes from the "one by one" nature in which the notes were selected

Comment: @JMoravitz After the last edit of the question there is no ambiguity anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Note, a number is divisible by both $2$ and $3$ if and only if it is divisible by $6$. Furthermore, there are only $11$ two-digit numbers that have distinct and non-zero digits, and divisible by $6$.

These are

$$12, 18, 24, 36, 42, 48, 54, 72, 78, 84, 96.$$

As previously noted, there are $72$ possible ways to place the two digits. Thus, the probability of making a number divisible by both $2$ and $3$ is

$$\fbox{11/72}.$$